# The generate if condition must be a constant expression

Tags: if-statement, verilog, modelsim

I am trying to create an Immediate Generator for RISC-V assembly, but I have encountered an error with `if` statement.

Here is my code in Verilog:

```
module signextend(in, out, sel);
    parameter nin = 32;
    parameter nout = 32;
    input [nin-1:nin-25] in;
    input [2:0] sel;
    output [nout-1:0] out;
    
    if (sel == 3'b000)
        begin
            assign out[19:0] = in[31:12];
            assign out[31:20] = {12{in[31]}};
        end
    else if (sel == 3'b001) 
        begin
            assign out[11:0] = in[31:20];
            assign out[31:12] = {20{in[31]}};
        end
    else if (sel == 3'b010)
        begin
            assign out[4:0] = in[24:20];
            assign out[31:5] = 0;
        end
    else if (sel == 3'b011)
        begin
            assign out[3:0] = in[11:8];
            assign out[4:9] = in[30:25];
            assign out[10] = in[7];
            assign out[11] = in[31];
            assign out[31:12] = {20{in[31]}};
        end
    else if (sel == 3'b100)
        begin
            assign out[4:0] = in[11:7];
            assign out[11:5] = in[31:25];
            assign out[31:12] = {20{in[31]}};
        end
    else if (sel == 3'b101)
        begin
            assign out[9:0] = in[21:30];
            assign out[10] = in[20];
            assign out[18:11] = in[19:12];
            assign out[19] = in[31];
            assign out[31:20] = {12{in[31]}};
        end 
    else 
        assign out = 32'hxxxx;  
endmodule
```

The problem exists in each `if` statement:

> The generate if condition must be a constant expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all your code inside an `always` block and remove the `assign`s:

```
always @(*) begin
  if (sel == 3'b000)
      begin
          out[19:0] = in[31:12];
          out[31:20] = {12{in[31]}};
      end
  else if (sel == 3'b001) 
    // etc
```

An `always` block contains *a little bit of software* (your `if` statements) that models *a little bit of hardware* (the resulting combinational logic).

It is legal to have an `if` statement outside an `always` (or `initial`) block, but then it means something different. Then it means conditional including of hardware, ie *if some condition is true, include this hardware*. Such a *condition* has to be *static*, ie fixed at compile time. It cannot be an input, like your `sel`. If you think about it, that makes total sense: how could you create some hardware that magically appears and disappears depending on the value of some input? You can't. That is why you are getting your error.

You need to remove the `assign`s, because while it is legal to have an `assign` inside an `always` block, it means something weird. Never do it.