# Why do I get this error: Illegal operation for constant expression?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am getting error for the below piece of code.

The same error is coming for `state_check_core`.

```
assign state_check_core = (post_vinout_force0_1p5.v_eq >=0.675 & post_vinout_force0_1p5.v_eq <= 0.825) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
assign state_check_dgo = (post_vinout_force0_1p5.v_eq >=1.35 & post_vinout_force0_1p5.v_eq <= 1.65) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
//setting the outputs
wire out_limit;
if(state_check_dgo==1'b1) begin
assign out_limit = ((vdd_1p5.v_eq>=1.35 & vdd_1p5.v_eq<=1.65) & (vdd_main>=0.675 & vdd_main<=0.825) & (vss==0.00)  & ((post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65 ) & (post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65)) & (i_force0 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force0 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_force1 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force1 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_1p5 >= 3.5e-03 & i_1p5 <= 4e-03)) ;
end
```

**ERROR:**

```
if(state_check_dgo==1'b1) begin
                 |
xmvlog: *E,NOTPAR (../a_ip_post_imx_ts_cln5p.v,184|17): Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
    if(state_check_core==1'b1)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463776/the-generate-if-condition-must-be-a-constant-expression

Answer (score 1):

The `if` needs to be inside an `always` block; otherwise, the simulator thinks you are using a `generate`, which expects `state_check_dgo` to be a constant (like a `parameter`).

In this case, you would not have an `assign` inside an `always` block, and you need to change `out_limit` from `wire` to `reg`.

```
reg out_limit;
always @* begin
    if (state_check_dgo==1'b1) begin
        out_limit = ((vdd_1p5.v_eq>=1.35 & vdd_1p5.v_eq<=1.65) & (vdd_main>=0.675 & vdd_main<=0.825) & (vss==0.00)  & ((post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65 ) & (post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65)) & (i_force0 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force0 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_force1 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force1 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_1p5 >= 3.5e-03 & i_1p5 <= 4e-03)) ;
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

assign out_limit = (state_check_dgo==1'b1) ? ((vdd_1p5.v_eq>=1.35 & vdd_1p5.v_eq<=1.65) & (vdd_main>=0.675 & vdd_main<=0.825) & (vss==0.00)  & ((post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense0_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65 ) & (post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq>= 1.35 & post_vinout_sense1_1p5.v_eq<= 1.65)) & (i_force0 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force0 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_force1 >= 1.35e-03 & i_force1 <= 1.65e-03) & (i_1p5 >= 3.5e-03 & i_1p5 <= 4e-03)):0 ;

let check this logic by using mux logic

Comment: Please could you format your code? Currently it is illegible.